# dotnet core: How do I get Entity Framework to read the connection string from a config file?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am migrating a .NET 4.x application (Class library and MS Test project, no web app) to dotnet core 2.1 and I cannot work out how to pass my SQL Database connection string to Entity Framework.

In .NET 4.x I had app.config and this code and entity framework magically used the connection string from the app.config file. easy :)

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ApplicationDataConnectionString" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and a DBContext where pass in a Database name

```
public class ApplicationDataDbContext : DbContext
{
    …

    public ApplicationDataDbContext(string databaseName) : base("name=ApplicationDataConnectionString")
    {
}
```

Dotnet core has no app.config and no configuration manager. So … I can read the connection string from a config file and do something like this, but how I come from there and pass it to the DBContext, I don't know … plus this approach feels wrong also.

```
public class ApplicationDataDbContext : DbContext
{
    …

    public ApplicationDataDbContext(string databaseName) : base("name=ApplicationDataConnectionString")
    {

            _config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

            var myConnectionString = _config.GetConnectionString("ApplicationData");
}
```

This is how I use the DBContext

```
public void SomeMethod()
    {
        using (var context = new ApplicationDataDbContext(Common.Constants.ApplicationDataDBName))
        {
          ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll have a `appsettings.json` containing your connection strings: `{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "YourDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=YourDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
}`

Comment: And if I do that, will entity framework load the connection string like I am used to in old .net?

Comment: Indeed - it's all here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings#aspnet-core

Comment: Perfect. Thank you :)

Comment: I got it to work :)

Comment: Good news! Maybe i should add it as a proper answer for you to tick...? :)

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Please add that you need to install the dotnet core version of EF. I had the net framework version installed

Comment: So what is the answer, I know you got it to work, but how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by following these instructions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings#aspnet-core

Please note that you need to install the dotnet core version of EF. I had the net framework version installed.